# Looking for a way to have a facebook "Like Gate" on my articles

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am looking to add a Like Gate to my articles similar to something seen on this blog:

http://www.wetpaint.com/the-bachelorette/articles/reality-steve-on-bachelor-pad-3-two-of-emilys-guys-join-the-cast-plus-whos-returning

Can anyone point me to a direction where I could implement this?  Would it be a plug-in or a custom piece of code?   Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the reference site has is a modal dialog that gets dismissed by an onClick event on one of the links. One of those links takes you to like Facebook. There is another "No Thanks" link that just shows the content.

The Facebook popup at the bottom of the page is the [Facebook Recommendations Bar](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendationsbar/). The link takes you to the official documentation. This allows your site to publish "*You* just read *some article* on *this website*" to a visitor's news feed.

A real like gate is no longer allowed. Facebook has deprecated most of the methods that make a like gate possible. See [Facebook Platform Policies Section IV. Point 1](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration) says "You must not ... gate content behind ... Facebook social channels...." The "No Thanks" link keeps them in compliance with the TOS.

Comment: Right, my goal is to have a popup show up over a section of the article where they can click 'like', maybe go to twitter, or close it out, similar to what they have with 'like us'.  Is that a simple feature to add?

Comment: Sure. There are lots of ways to add a modal dialog. If you're using Wordpress there are several ready-made plugins that will pop up a "like" box after a minute or two.

Comment: I tried this using [WP Super Popup](http://wppluginspro.com/wp-super-popup-pro/) and [Modal Dialog](http://yannickcorner.nayanna.biz/modal-dialog/) on one of my sites for a while. Conversions, ad revenue **and** new likes dropped off dramatically so I killed that program.

Comment: Yikes, maybe I'll just stick with what I have now.  I don't want things to drop off

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for Facebook for Websites. You can read more here... http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/